# Are the transaction scopes in Entity Framework only valid for the specific connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework in a web application and I have a piece of code communicating with the database that is inside a transaction like this:

```
using (DbContextTransaction transScope = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
{
    // some code here.
    transScope.Commit();
}
```

The isolation level `Serializable`, from what I read is supposed to be the highest level of isolation, preventing even reads from the records that have been accessed during this transaction (which is what I need).

However, when I accessed the SQL Server through another connection with SSMS (**while this transaction was mid execution**), I was able to access the rows read by this transaction.

So, what I want to know is: are transaction scopes and isolation levels valid only for the current connection, or are they valid for all connections to the database?

**EDITED**

What I am trying to prevent is:

1. Request A reads record with id 1 in the database. Column C has value 10.
2. Request B reads the same record in the database. Column C has value 10.
3. Request A updates the record with value of C = 11.
4. Request B updates the record with value of C = 11.

In this case in the end the value would be 11 but it should be 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction - or more precisely: the locks they take and hold - are of course database-wide - they are specifically designed to prevent other transactions / sessions from doing certain things.

And yes, the `Serializable` isolation level is the "highest", most restrictive isolation level - if your transaction reads rows and uses some conditions in the `WHERE` clause, SQL Server will use range-based **(S)** shared locks to prevent any other transaction from **modifying** (updating, deleting, or even inserting into these locked ranges) any data.

***BUT***: reading transactions use **shared locks** (S) by default, and those **DO NOT** prevent other transactions from **reading** those rows - shared locks, as the name implies, *can be shared* between reading transactions.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the records accessed by the transaction from being read? See post update for the case I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @EndiZhupani: well, if you need to prevent any other transactions from reading a row, you need to read it with more than just a (S) shared lock - you need to put an exclusive (X) lock onto that row and hang on to it (until your transaction is done). See [SQL Server table hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017) for details, and see [this blog post of a warning about XLOCK](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2006/12/13/does-xlock-always-prevent-reads-by-others.aspx)

Comment: @EndiZhupani: but if you're just trying to increment a number, **don't do this yourself** - let SQL Server handle this for you. Use an `INT IDENTITY` column, or if you can't use that, use a `SEQUENCE` object (in SQL Server **2012** and newer) to handle the incrementing of a counter

Comment: The `IDENTITY` column is incremented with each new record, right? And the `SEQUENCE` object database-wide as far as I know. The column I'm trying to increment is a download count. So, each row is incremented by its own. Which is why I don't think I can use those. But I think I'll handle this with a transaction inside a stored procedure and an exclusive lock during reads. Thanks for the (X) lock suggestion.